# Why javac not checks the undeclared TypeParameter in this case?

Tags: java, javac

There is a question related to Java generics. Please see following piece of code.

```
class Beta{
    
    public void hello(){}
}
class Alpha {
    public <Anything> void greet(Beta beta) {
        beta.hello();
    }

}
```

In the method `greet()`, `<Anything>` is not declared any where. Why does javac not throw any error in this case?

Comment: Why should it raise an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only occurence of`<Anything>` is it's declaration.
It is declared for the scope of the method but never used.

Take the following example from the Java Language Specification for a generic method:

```
class CollectionConverter {
<T> List<T> toList(Collection<T> c) {...}
}
```

The first `<T>` declares the type argument. The second and third one use it for the return type and for an argument type.

Your example is basically just the first `<T>` without actual usage. A little weird, but not a problem.

Comment: so with the same logic ```public <Anything extends Integer> void greet(Beta beta)``` is also valid?

Comment: sure. 123456789 <-character limit.